# Python BeautifulSoup content between span

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a web crawler.

The content on the web is

```
<span id="BrojPregleda">2</span>
```

I want to get the number 2. My current setup is:

```
    for view_counter in soup.find_all("span", id="BrojPregleda"):
    broj_pregleda = view_counter
    print(broj_pregleda)
```

But I get this printed out

```
<span id="BrojPregleda"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. For getting the text just use view_counter.text

```
for view_counter in soup.find_all("span", id="BrojPregleda"):
    print(view_counter.text)
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. I've got a similar for loop for getting something else on the page and that works.

I changed it to print("View Count: ", broj_pregleda.text) .Just outputs "View Count:" with no number

Comment: @dovla try this - print(view_counter.text)

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi i miss typed broj_pregleda.text and view_counter.text in my other reply, I did in fact do view_counter.text, but it just displays an empty line.

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi the problem was in the website you probably tested on your own html file. thanks tho

Comment: @dovla yes. i tested on own html file. you're welcome.